# UFT doesn't click a Radio button based on the adjacent text

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am using UFT 15.0.2 to automatize some Web GUI Tests using VB Script. I have to click on a Radio Button which is adjacent to a text (product code) but it doesn't work because when I used Record to click on the WebCheckBox, UFT pasted that line:

`Browser("B").Page("P").Frame("FrameID").WebElement("offRadio").Click`

[image: Adding product page]

Since this html page is under a Shadow-Root, none of the xpath/css is not working. Hence I am trying to use object repository to identify the radio button using the product code like how we write in xpath.

[image: Object spy of product]

Before shadowDOM implementation the code was working as below with xpath:

```
CheckBoxInputparam1 = "//span[text()='"
CheckBoxInputparam2 = "']/../../../../../../../../..//PAPER-CHECKBOX"
CheckBoxInputparam3 = "']/../../../../../../../../..//PAPER-RADIO-BUTTON"
checkboxXpath    = CheckBoxInputparam1&ProductList(0)&CheckBoxInputparam2
radioBtnXpath    = CheckBoxInputparam1&ProductList(0)&CheckBoxInputparam3
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: xpaths won't transcend into shadowdoms - you can try using relative identifiers (in the OR) or inject some JS with RunScript.  I wrote another answer recently on using JS and xpaths to get shadow dom interaction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68909696/clicking-side-panel-elements-in-selenium-without-iframes/68910313#68910313

Comment: Hi @RichEdwards, I am using QTP/UFT as the automation tool, so i cannot use JS in UFT unlike selenium. so need to know how i can merge 2 object repositories to identify an element ?

Comment: You can use JS - here's an example:  `Browser(...).Page(...).RunScript("window.scrollBy(0,10000)")`